# Solutions of $a^x = x$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How can I find a bound for the solutions of the following equation without using the Lambert function?

> $$a^x = x,$$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Look into the lambert w function

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @user62029: If you have a question you are trying to ask, you should ask it. Your comment suggests that you haven't done this.

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions for x? If so, x is real only if $a \leq e^\frac{1}{e}$ which can be found by maximizing $x^\frac{1}{x}$. Thus $x < e$ for real solutions

Comment: We need an abstract dupe for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are only looking for real solutions. Even if not, this answer can still be useful. We can see that for there to be a real solution, $a$ must be in the form $x^\frac{1}{x}$. Using calculus to maximize this gives that the maximum value of $x^\frac{1}{x}$ and thus the maximum value of $a$ is $e^\frac{1}{e}$. From this you get that the real solutions for $x$ have to be less than or equal to $e$.

For a lower bound, we can again use the same equation, noting that minimum value of $x^\frac{1}{x}$ approaches 0, and hence the lower bound for $x$ is 0.

Answer (score 2):

There are no algebraic "closed-form" expressions for the solutions. However, we can rewrite it as
$$\begin{align*}
-a^x&=-x\\
-1&=(-x)a^{(-x)}\\
-1&=(-x)e^{\ln(a)\cdot (-x)}\\
-\ln(a)&=(-\ln(a)x)e^{(-\ln(a)x)}\\
-\ln(a)&=ye^y,\quad\text{where } y=-\ln(a)x.
\end{align*}$$
The solution of this equation is, by the definition of the [*Lambert W function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function),
$$y=W(-\ln(a)),$$
which is to say
$$x=-\frac{W(-\ln(a))}{\ln(a)}.$$

Comment: -1. The OP has stated " Without that [function] I meant. A bound would be nice. "

Comment: @MathN00b He has stated it in the comments but it should be stated within the problem text itself.

Comment: @1110101001 even then, the answerer should have had enough caution to read the comments.

Comment: @MathNoob: When I started writing this answer, that comment hadn't been posted - writing is not instantaneous. Moreover, this is still useful for the OP. For example, one could use the Taylor series for $W$ to arrive at an approximate answer.